# Is there a way to construct a single dicom image from multiple dicom images in python (pydicom)?

Tags: python, pydicom

I have 4 different dicom images of a particular patient. I want to recreate a dicom image from them such that the final image shows the details of patient and 4 images on top of it.

[Output DCIM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUur4.jpg)

Comment: From the pydicom documentation it is not clear how one would write a multi-frame dicom file, but have a look at the standard: http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/2016e/output/chtml/part03/sect_C.7.6.6.html

Comment: Different slices? different modalities (CT, MR, ...)? if you wish to make your own, your target is secondary capture.